# Using the precise definition of limits to prove a limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

**Question**

Let $a$ be a positive real number. Use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limits to prove that $$\lim\limits_{x\to a}\ \frac {3x^2 + 2ax + a^2} {2x + a} = 2a\ .$$

---

**My working**

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.

For $|x - a| < \delta$, choose $\delta = \frac 1 3 \epsilon - 2a$.

\begin{align}
|x + a| & =
|x - a + 2a|
\\[5 mm] & \leq
|x - a| + 2a
\\[5 mm] & <
\frac 1 3 \epsilon
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\left|\frac {3x^2 + 2ax + a^2} {2x + a} - 2a\right| & =
\left|\frac {3x^2 - 2ax - a^2} {2x + a}\right|
\\[5 mm] & =
\left|\frac {(3x + a)(x - a)} {2x + a}\right|
\\[5 mm] & <
\left|\frac {3(x + a)(x - a)} {2(x - a)}\right|
\\[5 mm] & =
\frac 3 2 |x + a|
\\[5 mm] & <
\frac 1 2 \epsilon
\\[5 mm] & <
\epsilon
\end{align}

---

May I know if I have chosen a suitable $\delta$ and if my proof is logical? Any comments/suggestions to improve my working will be greatly appreciated :)

---

**Edit**

Thank you everyone for your inputs! I have learnt a lot :)

Comment: Sounds fine to me!

Comment: Maybe I missed something obvious, but why $\left|x-a\right|+2a<\frac{1}3\epsilon$ ?

Comment: There is also the issue of $\frac32 |x+a| < \epsilon$. When $x$ is near $a$ and $\epsilon = a$ (for example), this isn't true. Usually we set $\delta$ directly depending on $\epsilon$, and use $|x-a| < \delta$ to bound the difference to be less than $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $\delta$ doesn't work and it would be strange if it did, because in almost every case $\delta$ must be very close to $0$ when $\varepsilon$ is very close to $0$. But your $\delta$ is always greater than $2a$.

Note that$$\frac{3x^2+2ax+a^2}{2x+a}-2a=\frac{(3x+a)(x-a)}{2x+a}$$and that therefore$$\left|\frac{3x^2+2ax+a^2}{2x+a}-2a\right|=\left|\frac{3x+a}{2x+a}\right||x-a|.\tag1$$If $|x-a|<\frac a4$, then $|x|<\frac54a$ and so $|3x+a|<\frac{19}4a$. On the other hand,\begin{align}|2x+a|&=|2(x-a)+3a|\\&\geqslant3a-2|x-a|\\&>\frac52a.\end{align}So,$$\left|\frac{3x+a}{2x+a}\right|<\frac{19}{10}.$$Therefore, it follows from $(1)$ that $\delta=\min\left\{\frac a4,\frac{10}{19}\varepsilon\right\}$ will work.

Comment: Sorry, I realise my $\delta$ had a typo. Does my $\delta$ work now? The $+$ should have been a $-$.

Comment: If $\varepsilon=a$, your $\delta$ will be smaller than $0$. So, no, it does not work.

Comment: I see. This question is a tricky one. Also, may I know how you arrived at $|2x + a| \geq a - 2|x|$?

Comment: If $a,b\in\Bbb R$, $|a-b|\geqslant\bigl||a|-|b|\bigr|$.

Comment: Note that $2|x|<\frac a2$. So, $2|x|<a$, and therefore $a-2|x|>0$. It follows that $\bigl|a-2|x|\bigr|=a-2|x|$.

Comment: @DavidK Is there any mistake in my computations?

Comment: @DavidK You are right, of course. I think that it is correct now.

Comment: @DavidK That is corrected too now. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Nice proof!

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two major errors.

The first is where you try to choose $\delta$ in such a way to ensure that
$$|x - a| + 2a \stackrel?< \frac13 \epsilon. \tag1$$
Leaving aside the problems with your method of choosing $\delta,$
just take a good long look at Inequation $(1)$.

Now recall that $a$ is some given positive integer and that absolute values are never negative. Therefore the left hand side is never less than the positive number $2a.$
So if we just consider the case $\epsilon = a,$ it should be clear that
$\frac13 \epsilon = \frac13 a < 2a \leq |x - a| + 2a,$ and therefor Inequation $(1)$ is false for this particular choice of a positive number $\epsilon$.
Now do you recall that part of the definition of a limit where it says
"for all $\epsilon > 0$"?
It means that whatever you do, you have to have an answer for every positive $\epsilon.$ If there is even one positive $\epsilon$ for which your proof doesn't work, your proof doesn't work. And that's how it will go if you try to base a proof on Inequation $(1)$.

The second major error I found is here:
$$
\left|\frac {(3x + a)(x - a)}{2x + a}\right| \stackrel?<
\left|\frac {3(x + a)(x - a)}{2(x - a)}\right|. \tag2
$$

Note that the right-hand side is not even defined unless $x - a\neq 0,$
but in the context of the definition of a limit we actually have
$0 < |x-a| < \delta$, not just $|x-a| < \delta$, so that's OK.
And given that $x - a \neq 0,$ we can cancel a factor of $|x - a|$ on both sides, which means you actually need this to be true:
$$
\left|\frac {3x + a}{2x + a}\right| \stackrel?<
\left|\frac {3(x + a)}{2(x - a)}\right|.
$$

So let $x - a = t$, where $0 < |t| < \delta.$ Then $x = a + t$ and
$$
\left|\frac {3x + a}{2x + a}\right|
= \left|\frac {4a+3t}{3a + 2t}\right|.
$$
For very small values of $t$ the right-hand side is approximately $\frac 43.$

On the other hand,
$$
\left|\frac {3(x + a)}{2(x - a)}\right|
= \left|\frac {6a + 3t}{2t}\right|,
$$
which gets very large as $t$ gets very small.
For example, if $0 < t < \frac1{100}a,$
the right-hand side is greater than $200.$
So in order to show that Inequation $(2)$ is true, you need to show that at least some numbers greater than $200$ are approximately equal to $\frac 43.$
That is not true even for the largest possible value of $\frac43,$ so a proof that relies on Inequation $(2)$ won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your post! Though it does not provide me with an answer, others have and yours really gives me insight into why my answer would not work :) Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Often a substitution can simplify the calculations or clarify the issues. Let $f(x)=\frac {3x^2+2ax+a^2} {2x+a}$ when $2x+a\ne 0.$ Let $x=y+a.$ When $2x+a\ne 0$ we have $$|f(x)-2a|=|y|\cdot\frac {|a+3y|}{|3a+2y|}.$$ Now if $|y|<|a|$ then (i)... $|a+3y|\le |a|+3|y|<4|a|=4a\;$ and (ii)... $|3a+2y|\ge |3a|-|2y|>|a|=a>0,\;$ so (iii)... $\frac {|a+3y|}{|3a+2y|}<4,\;$ so $$|f(x)-2a|\le 4|y|.$$
So, given $\epsilon>0,$ let $\delta=\min(\epsilon/4, a).$ Now if $|x-a|<\delta$ then  $f(x)$ exists (because if $|x-a|<a>0$ then $2x+a\ne 0$) and $$|f(x)-2a|\le 4|y|=4|x-a|<4\delta\le\epsilon.$$

Comment: Note that we do not need a good estimate for $|a+3y|/|3a+2y|$, just a common upper bound, $4,$ for all $y\in (0, 2a).$

Comment: $|y|=|x-a|.$ We are not interested in what happens when $|x-a|\ge |a|$....... $0<\delta\le a=|a|$ so if $|x-a|<\delta$ then $|y|=|x-a|<\delta\le |a|$... Given $\epsilon >0,$ we want a small-enough interval $J=(a-\delta, a+\delta)$  that (1) if $x\in J$ then $|f(x)-2a|\le 4|y|,$ and (2)  if $x\in J$ then $4|y|<\epsilon$. Condition (1) is met if $\delta\le a$. Condition (2) is met if $\delta\le \epsilon/4$. So both conditions are met if $\delta=\min(\epsilon/4,a).$